# Reconstructing a matrix from a structure

Tags: matlab, region

I use the function `regionprops` with properties `FilledImage` on a matrix 1000x1000 and it gives me  a structure with 1 field of several logical matrix of different size. How can I reconstruct with these different  matrix  a new  matrix of size 1000x1000 in the aim to visualise the result obtain with `reionpropros` and compare it with the visualisation of the initial matrix ?

here a enxemple with a matrix 38x25

```
clear all 
close all


I=[false,true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,true;false,false,true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,true,true,true,true,true,false,false,true,true,false;false,false,false,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,false,false,false,false,true,true,true,true,false,false;false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false;false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false;false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false;false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false;false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false;false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false;false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false;false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false;false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false;false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false;false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false;false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false;true,true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,true,true;false,false,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,false,true,true,true,false,false,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,false;false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,true,false,false,false,true,true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false;false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false;false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false;false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false;false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false;false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false;false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false;false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false;false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false;false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false;true,true,true,true,true,true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false;false,false,false,false,false,false,true,true,false,false,false,true,true,true,true,true,true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false;false,false,false,false,false,false,false,true,true,true,true,true,false,false,false,false,false,true,true,false,false,false,false,false,false;false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,true,true,true,true,false,false;false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,true,true;false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false;false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false;false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false;false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false;false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false;false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false];
figure, imagesc(I)
s=regionprops(I,'FilledImage');
figure, imagesc(s)

Error using image
There is no FilledImage property on the Image class.

Error in imagesc (line 18)
hh = image(varargin{1},'CDataMapping','scaled');

Error in question (line 8)
figure, imagesc(s)
```

Comment: Please, add a [mcve]. It is a bit unclear what you are looking for

Comment: Also, it is hard to diagnose the error. Look at the error stack and tell us on what line exactly the error is thrown. I suspect that you should call `imagesc(s.FilledImage)` instead. Cannot test it though as I do not have the image processing toolbox.

Comment: it is the second imagesc the problem. it's why I want rebuild the matrix with matrix of structure

Comment: And did you try to call `imagesc` as I suggested?

Comment: Yes I have an Error : Incorrect number of arguments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation entry](https://mathworks.com/help/images/ref/regionprops.html#input_argument_d0e125264) of the `'FilledImage'` property reads:

> Returns a binary image (logical) of the same size as the bounding box
>   of the region. The on pixels correspond to the region, with all holes
>   filled in, as shown in this figure.
>
> [image: Documentation FilledImage property]

---

The image that you provided looks like this:

```
I=[false,true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,true;false,false,true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,true,true,true,true,true,false,false,true,true,false;false,false,false,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,false,false,false,false,true,true,true,true,false,false;false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false;false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false;false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false;false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false;false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false;false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false;false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false;false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false;false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false;false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false;false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false;false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false;true,true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,true,true;false,false,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,false,true,true,true,false,false,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,false;false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,true,false,false,false,true,true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false;false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false;false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false;false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false;false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false;false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false;false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false;false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false;false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false;false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false;true,true,true,true,true,true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false;false,false,false,false,false,false,true,true,false,false,false,true,true,true,true,true,true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false;false,false,false,false,false,false,false,true,true,true,true,true,false,false,false,false,false,true,true,false,false,false,false,false,false;false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,true,true,true,true,false,false;false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,true,true;false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false;false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false;false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false;false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false;false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false;false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false];

figure;
imagesc(I);
```

[image: Image provided by OP]

Since the image has three regions that are not connected (yellow lines), then the `struct` (`s`) returned by the [`regionprops`](https://mathworks.com/help/images/ref/regionprops.html) function will contain three different images.

```
>> s = regionprops(I, 'FilledImage')

s = 

  3×1 struct array with fields:

    FilledImage
```

If you wish to visualize the images in separate figure windows, you will have to loop through `s` like this:

```
I=[false,true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,true;false,false,true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,true,true,true,true,true,false,false,true,true,false;false,false,false,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,false,false,false,false,true,true,true,true,false,false;false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false;false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false;false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false;false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false;false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false;false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false;false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false;false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false;false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false;false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false;false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false;false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false;true,true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,true,true;false,false,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,false,true,true,true,false,false,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,false;false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,true,false,false,false,true,true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false;false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false;false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false;false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false;false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false;false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false;false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false;false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false;false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false;false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false;true,true,true,true,true,true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false;false,false,false,false,false,false,true,true,false,false,false,true,true,true,true,true,true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false;false,false,false,false,false,false,false,true,true,true,true,true,false,false,false,false,false,true,true,false,false,false,false,false,false;false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,true,true,true,true,false,false;false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,true,true;false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false;false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false;false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false;false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false;false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false;false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false];

figure;
imagesc(I);

s = regionprops(I, 'FilledImage');

for i = 1:length(s)
    figure;
    imagesc(s(i).FilledImage);
end
```

---

On the other hand, if you wish to visualize the images in the same figure window you can use [`subplot`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/subplot.html):

```
figure;
for i = 1:length(s)
    subplot(3, 1, i);
    imagesc(s(i).FilledImage);
end
```

This is the result:

[image: Three images in subplot]

Comment: is it not possible to visualize them on an unique image and not on three?

Comment: @Mac. Yes, it is possible to do that using [`subplot`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/subplot.html). I will update my answer.